# custom field to always to .get_the_title()?

Tags: custom-field, get-the-title

Is there a way to have always the `the_title()` tag also includes a custom field called subtitle?

I want to have a title like this: "*subtitle-custom-field: Post Title*". For example, "*Cool: The new TV show from Werner Herzog*."

In this case, *cool* would be the custom field value, and *the new TV...* would be `the_title()`.

I am getting this at the moment with the following code:

```
<h1><?php $values = get_post_custom_values("myCustomField"); echo $values[0]; ?>: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php $values = get_post_custom_values("myCustomField"); echo $values[0]; ?>

<p><?php the_title(); ?></p></h1>
```

The Problem is, that Google indexes the posts sometimes with the custom field in title, sometimes without it - which in some cases makes no sense. I also gave all possible "*title tags*" the complete title the same way in the `title=` attribute.

Is there any way to tell WordPress if there's a custom field subtext, print it always in front of the `post_title`?

Comment: What theme are you using? Link it please (if custom: show your header.php code). And please also edit your post and format code properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
function add_subtitle($title, $id) {
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($id, 'myCustomField', true);
    $new_title = $title;
    if(!empty($subtitle))
        $new_title = $subtitle . ': ' . $new_title;
    return $new_title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'add_subtitle', 10, 2);
```

Basically, this uses the `the_title` filter to add the subtitle to your title.  It only adds it if that custom field is available, otherwise, it leaves the title alone.

Comment: +1, I was writing similar answer, but you beat me, so added an alternative method.

Comment: Using filter is recommended unless you don't want the change globally _( ie - Other plugin/function using `the_title()` or `get_the_title()` gets the new formatted title if filter is used )_

Comment: @amit which is why I did a check for that custom field he is using as the subtitle.  If the post doesn't have it, the title isn't effected.

Answer (score 1):

[`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) Accept parameters, we can use them to pass the custom field value to show either before or after the title.

### Example -

```
<?php the_title( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myCustomField', TRUE) ); ?>
```

**Note -** Make sure you set the 3rd parameter as `TRUE`, which will return a single `STRING`,

### Edit #1-

```
/*  
 *  The OneLiner ( Note the DOT between two strings ) 
 *  OutPut - Foo: the post title
 */
the_title( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myCustomField', TRUE) . ': ');
```

Reference Codex - [Function Reference - `the title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Comment: Didn't realize it took arguments like that.  Pretty sweet.

Comment: Nice - and how can I set that the custom field shows up before the title? And how could I do a ':' betwenn them?